# Authentication error when adding table using linked server

Tags: ssas, windows-authentication

In SQL Server, I created a view which uses a linked server.  The view runs fine from within Management Studio.  But when I try to add it into SSAS I get the error:

Deferred prepare could not be completed - not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

In the linked server, I'm using the login's current security context.  I tried adding that login to the list of local servers in the Linked Server Properties without success.  I continue to get the error in the DSV.

Other posts suggest making sure the remote server uses SQL Server authentication, but I can't make any modifications to the remote server.  I can access it fine however using Management Studio, so should't I be able to access it with SSAS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSAS requires Windows Authentication - if you are accessing the remote server via a SQL username/password then you will not be able to add that view to your SSAS DSView.

Why not just dump the table to another server you do access through windows auth?

Comment: Dumping the table to the main server would work, if I knew how to do it during the qeury, rather than running a separate (ie nightly) integration service (it's a very large amount of data).  Is there a way to do this on the fly?  Also, I'm not clear on why the problem exists in the first place, since I am able to access the remote server using Window auth.

Comment: Nevermind, even though I was hesitant, I went ahead and added a read-only SQL-Auth user, and now it works fine.  I marked the Answer since it would have been the solution otherwise.  Thanks.